# Go back from Xib to different ViewController in StoryBoard

Tags: objective-c, xib, viewcontroller

I've StoryBoard and xib in my project.
I know how to go to xib from storyboard, this is the code:

```
ChosenPlacesViewController *cpvc = [[ChosenPlacesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChosenPlacesViewController" bundle:nil];
    [cpvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:cpvc animated:NO];
```

But how do I go from the xib to different ViewController in my StoryBoard?

I know I can use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
```

But I want to go to different ViewController(TabBar StoryBoard), not the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should find out more about navigation view controller. It depends what is your hierarchy of view controllers. There is a viewControllers property. You can set new order of controllers, last one will be visible.

More info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html